# How c++ allocate memory for class member functions?

Tags: c++

I am curious how c++ allocate memory for class member function.

Then, I create two objects of class A; let say A and B. I know that both objects will have their own memory for storing n variable. But, how's about function one?
Will a compiler allocate two blocks of memory; one for function one of A and the other one for function one of B??

````
class A
{
int n;
void function1() {}
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only one instance of the function code. The `this` pointer that gets passed to that function is how it knows what object it's working with.